# Firebase session length new console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I can't seem to find the session length config in the new console. Also couldn't find any literature on it or session management in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the new firebase version the session length is managed automatically for you, this means the sessions are alive as long as possible (not a specific timeframe) so users have to sign in less frequently. Only if an account changes drastically like password reset, email change etc. the session is revoked for security reasons. The only way to terminate a session manually is y calling the sign out method for each platform