# After 24 hours Firebase stops working but if I update pods it starts working again

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on **Firebase** and I have one query. I have login through Firebase and have fired insert, update, delete queries.

Here is my code:

```
[self.data observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSArray *array = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"%@",array);
    }];
```

This block works perfectly but after every **24** hours it stops calling. However, if I update *pod* then again it starts working.

Comment: can you enable logging in the app and check for logs. it might show useful logs to find out the error

Comment: no there is no such kind of error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on new Firebase there is no option to manage session like old so you just need to call sign Out API if your session expired:

```
NSError *error;
[[FIRAuth auth] signOut:&error];
if (!error) {
  // Sign-out succeeded
}
```

And force to user signIn again so there is no need to install firebase pod again.

---

If you are old Firebase user then manage it by following:

If you check the [Firebase Persisting User Auth State](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-persisting-auth)

> When a user authenticates, the default session length is 24 hours from initial authentication. This means that the user's authentication state will automatically be persisted between page loads. You can configure the session length by navigating to the Login & Auth section of your Firebase App Dashboard and configuring the Session Length dropdown on the top right. Every auth provider has an optional remember parameter.

**So Tokens issued to the authenticated users are valid for 24 hours by default. You can change this from the Login & Auth tab on the App Dashboard.**

Comment: In new firebase dashboard there is no such tab....so i am not able to change session length

Comment: if you are migrate your old app to new there is no session maintain option that will be managed automatically check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346251/firebase-session-length-new-console and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487283/firebase-3-x-token-session-expiration

Comment: you also can identifier : FIRAuthErrorCodeUserTokenExpired : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors

Comment: join us on chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family : lots of dev hoi :D